# Django-nonrel Status

Tags: django, mongodb, nosql

Is Django-nonrel still active? I am interested on developing an e-commerce website that involves tons of catalogs and it seems like NoSQL is the best approach for this. I have background in Django but from what I found out, vanilla Django does not support NoSQL.

Enter the Django-nonrel as the alternative. However I am a bit concerned on the project continuity and community. Django-nonrel is a forked of Django 1.3, does this mean that it us outdated (since current Django is 1.5), or does it has its own circle and version after the fork?

In short, what is the status of Django-nonrel? Active?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want to use MongoDB as the main database.

Comment: A more obvious place to check activity would be the [django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django) repository on Github.  There appear to be some recent commits as well as `nonrel-1.4` and `nonrel-1.5-beta` branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently discussed here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/1cdrqs/using_mongodb_with_django_whats_the_status/
where the following stands out:

> > "It does not exist yet. And I'd strong recommend not using MongoDB unless you have a good use-case for it. Needing lots of reads/writes in some parts isn't enough to justify it IMO. MongoDB's read/write performance falls back down to earth once it's put in a real world scenario.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > Disclaimer: I'm a dev working on a series of MongoDB apps that service hundreds of thousands of users and wish very much my predecessors just went with Postgres."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, I am using for a year now and is working fine, the only downside, at least for me is that you can't do contains search.
If you want to change ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

django-nonrel is not active now, I´m testing the last version, it´s a django 1.6.11 fork

git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.6

working with postgre and mongodb as DB engines simultaneously and it works